# Threading requires that an application's button be clicked twice

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following code. submitClick() is triggered when someone clicks the submit button on my application. In the past, submit click would be click once, and all of submitFile() would be carried out. By adding the threading addition to checkContent(), now submitClick has to be clicked twice for all of submitFile() to be completed. Is there any way to make it so that submitFile() finishes (with checkContent()) so the user only has to press my apps submit button?

Thank you in advance.

```
public void submitClick(View v) throws Exception{
    if (!submitted) { submitFile(); }
}

public void submitFile() {
    checkContent();
    if (valid) {
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageAddress).into(imagePreview);
        saveImage();
        //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); //refreshes system to show saved file
        submitted = true;
        submit_but.setText("Encrypt");
    }
}

private void checkContent() {
    media = null;
    if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            boolean img = false;
            boolean youtube = false;
            public void run() {
                URLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = new URL(imageAddress).openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
                img = contentType.startsWith("image/");
                if(img)
                    media = "image";
                if (!img) {
                    // Check host of url if youtube exists
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
                    if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost())) {
                        media = "youtube";
                        youtube = true;
                    }
                }
                valid = img || youtube;
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Thread` will finish after the call to `if (valid)` and the rest in the `submitFile()`.

Easy fix is to include the entire `submitFile()` in a Thread, instead of just part of it. If the logic is bound to each other, it's better off that they're together.

A more android-esque fix is to use AsyncTask, as such:

```
public void submitClick(View v) throws Exception {
    if (!submitted) { submitFile(); }
}

public void submitFile() {
    if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {  
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                boolean img = false;
                boolean youtube = false;
                URLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = new URL(imageAddress).openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
                img = contentType.startsWith("image/");
                if(img)
                    media = "image";
                if (!img) {
                    // Check host of url if youtube exists
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
                    if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost())) {
                        media = "youtube";
                        youtube = true;
                    }
                }
                return img || youtube;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid) {
                if (valid) {
                    Picasso.with(this).load(imageAddress).into(imagePreview);
                    saveImage();
                    //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); //refreshes system to show saved file
                    submitted = true;
                    submit_but.setText("Encrypt");
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: I get errors on"protected Long doInBackground". It says that doInBackground(Void) clashes with doInBackground(Param). How could I correct this?

Also Picasso.with(this)... throws an error with "this" saying that Picasso cannot be applied to an AsyncTask